# What classes (based on modifier) can be accessed by super.()?

Tags: java, class

I'm not sure if I understand correctly whether I can access all kind of classes based on their [modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215505/1447885) (even the private ones) from the super.() or just the public and protected ones.

If I extend a class it's a subclass of the first, so `super` can bring me only the `protected` and `public` ones. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but you really should RTFM http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: yes, super will give you access to public protected or default ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

super.method() will let you call "method()" in the superclass, if you are overriding method() in the subclass. It's not a question of what you can access with super, but what methods you can override in a subclass:

- public
- protected
- default (no qualifier) IF the subclass is in the same package as the superclass.

And only if the method isn't final.